# Using .trigger() on a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, dynamic, triggers, click, element

I'm trying to trigger a click event on a dynamically created element. I have used .on() to bind the click events, but it seems that the trigger method is firing before the element is created. I have tried triggering the click in several locations and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to trigger a click on the first span that is created using $('container:first-child').trigger('click');

```
displayThumbnails = function() {

        $(photoArray).each(function(index) {
            var thumbnailImg = this.SmallImageUrl,
            largeImg = this.LargeImageUrl,
            thumbnailId = 'thumbnail' + index,
            largeImgId = 'image' + index;

            if(index > indexCount) {
                return false;
            } else if (index >= indexStartValue && index <= indexCount) {

                $(thumbContainer).append(
                    '<span class="thumbnail" id="' + thumbnailId + '"><img height="45px" width="60px" src="' + thumbnailImg + '"/></span>'
                );

                $(thumbContainer).on('click', '#' + thumbnailId, function(){
                    $(thumbContainer).find('.active').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    $('#displayed-image').attr('src', largeImg);
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I don't see the trigger in your code but you would want to use .on() to bind the click event to your element, and make sure that the trigger call to the click event is fired in the callback of the element being added or some other time once you're certain it exists in the DOM.

Comment: This is what I assumed the issue was, but the problem is that I need it to somehow be attached to the above function. This function is called several times, and I'm trying to use the trigger to populate the #display-image div every time a new set of images is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months later, I'm revisiting this. The answer IMO these days is that triggering a click in order to have a subsequent function call is too interdependent. If you are trying to trigger a click to make something happen on your page, you are probably thinking about it the wrong way. I ended up rethinking this and had a function that handled loading the large image on its own. Basically, I was trying to trigger the click to load an image.

By rethinking the process, I ended up with much cleaner code - everything working independently to handle a small function.

Also, the reason that I never accepted the other two answers is that .on() is the way to go for binding event handlers in jQuery as of 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think what may be failing is the binding between the new control and your trigger function. Try using "live" in stead of "on"

```
$(thumbContainer).live('click', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element is created after .on is called then it won't have the event bound to it.

As @AlejoBrz mentioned you can try using [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) but you could also look at the [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function as that could work depending on your situation too.

[edit] Just realised that .on is exactly the same as .delegate when used as you have. So on second thoughts seeing as you are binding an event just after creation of the element maybe you could just replace the .on line with this:

```
$('#' + thumbnailId).bind('click', function () { // the rest of your code here
```

I should note that this solution won't scale very well as the number of thumbnails grows.